# Understanding Lagrangian/Hamiltonian Mechanics

Tags: soft-question, physics, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

I am trying to understand Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics, and I have a few small questions based on guesses I have had. I admit that I do not have all of the background in topology to understand a lot of what I have seen, but I am pretty comfortable with diff eq, etc.

These are more like guesses based on what I have been reading so far (mostly *Mechanics* by Landau and Lifshitz, as well as various papers on PDEs and both calculus of variations and analytic mechanics. If you'd like, I can try to dig up my reading material, but it might be difficult to find everything). Please let me know if these are correct interpretations, as if they are not, I am confident that I am sorely missing something.

Also, these are specifically for mechanics problems.

1. The Lagrangian functional is at most quadratic in $q(t)$, as any higher degree would eliminate the possibility of only one $q(t)$ minimizing the action (I'm certain that this would be true if $q(t)$ was a scalar, but I don't know anything about function space).
2. The action functional must have definite bounds, otherwise a similar problem occurs as did in my first assumption. In a sense, the necessity of defined bounds can be thought of as a constraint.
3. This one is more of a question, I just haven't found a good explanation of it using jargon I understand:
   Is the Lagrangian function created when one uses the Lagrange multiplier method for optimization sort of the same as the Lagrangian function $L=T-U$, where $T$ is a function to be optimized and $U$ is a constraint function? I'm not really sure about this, but it could be helpful to understand a lot of necessary requirements in Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics as direct results of adapting Lagrange's method of optimization for functionals rather than scalar functions.

Please let me know if I am completely missing the point, criticism is very helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To address a comment which I removed from your post, it is fine to post a question like this at math.se because it involves the mathematical tools. You could also have chosen to post it at physics.se, probably. You would get a different type of answer there, I suppose. But be aware that it's not good to post the same question on two sites simultaneously without being explicit that you are doing so.  Usually it's better to pick one and then move the question if things go badly.

Comment: And also a belated "welcome to math.se!"

Comment: @nicholascallahan you might be interested in [my journal post related to learning mechanics.](https://ryancschwiebert.wordpress.com/2021/09/14/study-log-getting-up-to-speed-on-noethers-theorems-on-invariance/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only really half-knowledgeable about this, but I *have* been thinking about it recently and do think I can address your questions.

1. No, to the best of my knowledge a Lagrangian can be non-quadratic (and indeed can even contain non-polynomial expressions in terms of the inputs.)  You're right that this can complicate the search for extrema.  However, it's usually assumed you are in a region that is locally convex, so that an extrema exists. I've read that "most" Lagrangians you encounter in nature are like that.
2. I don't know what you mean by "definite bounds" on the action functional. The action functional is a line integral which, by definition has a starting and stopping point, if that's what you mean.
3. My experience has been that the most typical case is the Lagrangian is $K-V$ where $K$ is the kinetic energy of a system and $V$ is a potential.  When further physical constraints are at play, then the method of Lagrange multipliers can be used to layer these constraints onto the Lagrangian, resulting in a different function with different solutions (ones which conform to the constraints.)

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I have one quick follow up question: I thought that the action functional was a scalar function? After all, the Lagrangian is a scalar function-- does the fact that it has function inputs mean that it can also be expressed directly as a line integral?

Comment: @NicholasCallahan It depends on what you mean by "scalar function."  I would describe $L$ as "a real valued function on the tangent bundle."  Of course it has to be "scalar"-valued to define the path integral, if that's what you mean.  The action is a function on the curves in the tangent bundle into $\mathbb R$.  The inputs to the action are paths in the tangent bundle and the output is a real number, the line integral over that path.  This permits you to 'score' paths for optimization.

Comment: lol, I am quickly approaching the conclusion that I will need to learn more topology to properly approach this :). At least I know that now! My statement that L is a scalar function is just what I've read in the literature, but I think it means in contrast to the conventional, obviously vector functions that one would use to solve physics problems in the Newtonian approach. However, I don't think that in practice these ideas contradict each other, though yours seems way more accurate and informed than mine. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @NicholasCallahan I do not see how more topology would help. Manifold theory, is maybe what you mean?

Comment: @NicholasCallahan When you say "foo-function" do you mean foo is the input or the output?  I'm sure every physics text agrees it is scalar output, but none of them would use only a scalar input exclusively...